# Flask Authentication Override for one Route

Tags: python, authentication, flask, overriding

I'm new to python and working on a small code for flask webserver.
I need a solution to achieve the below scenario.

I have app.py which calls settings.py for flask user ID and password and also a route.py to handble the routes.
Now I want users to be asked for authentication only for few routes and other routes should override authentication and perform operation based on specific users/specific host.
Can this be achieved?

As of now its asking for authentication for all the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a decorator. Decorators are usually called before the definition of a function you want to use (in this case whenever you want to authenticate your route).

**For example:**

```
def requires_auth():
    def wrapper(f):
        @wraps(f)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            if 'id' not in flask.session:
                return unauthorized_abort()
            else:
                if flask.session['first_login']:
                    return f(*args, **kwargs)
                else:
                    return flask.render_template('change_password.html')
        return decorated
    return wrapper
```

After writing this decorator, we can easily use authentication for particular routes only. This below code shows **@require_auth()** which will easily help for particular routes only.

```
@app.route('/data/get_data',methods=['GET'])
@requires_auth()
def get_data():
```

Answer (score 0):

Although the above answer solves my query, I was looking for more specific scenario.
Here's what I changed,

I commented #app.config['BASIC_AUTH_FORCE'] = True in flask settings

Here is what changed in routes.py
Added 
basic_auth = BasicAuth(app)
and I added this decorator
@basic_auth.required for the routes which requires authentication.

As a security measure, I am allowing Unauthenticated requests only from a specific host using headers.